# Como indexar el diccionario obtenido

Tags: php, array

Qué tal compañeros, el día de hoy estuve intentando realizar un diccionario en php, con la implementacion de la funcion **array_key_exists()** hago la creación de los niveles que necesito para este caso, sin embargo, el problema comienza cuando intento acceder a estos arrays, pues, dependiendo las consultas estos niveles se crean vacíos o mejor dicho con **""** como nombre del array, pondré el ejemplo del postman:

```
"subjects": {
        "N": {
            "": {
                "": {
                    "id_titular": null,
                    "titular": null,
                    "genero": null,
                    "asignaturas": [
                        {
                            "plan": "LICENCIATURA EN LA ENSEÑANZA DEL INGLÉS",
                            "name": "ASPECTOS PSICOLOGICOS DEL APRENDIZAJE DE LENGUAS - ",
                            "degree": "9",
                            "group": "A",
                            "hd": "0",
                            "ht": "0",
                            "htd": "4",
                            "hi": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "plan": "CURSO DE LA LENGUA INGLES",
                            "name": "BÁSICO 4 -CURSO NORMAL (LUNES A VIERNES)",
                            "degree": "4",
                            "group": "D",
                            "hd": "0",
                            "ht": "0",
                            "htd": "5",
                            "hi": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "plan": "LICENCIATURA EN LA ENSEÑANZA DEL INGLÉS",
                            "name": "DISEÑO DE PROGRAMAS DE INGLES COMO LENGUA EXTRANJERA - ",
                            "degree": "7",
                            "group": "A",
                            "hd": "0",
                            "ht": "0",
                            "htd": "4",
                            "hi": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "MPA": {
            "26-01-2023": {
                "": {
                    "id_titular": null,
                    "titular": null,
                    "genero": null,
                    "asignaturas": [
                        {
                            "plan": "CURSO DE LA LENGUA INGLES",
                            "name": "BÁSICO 1 -CURSO NORMAL (LUNES A VIERNES)",
                            "degree": "1",
                            "group": "DTSD",
                            "hd": "0",
                            "ht": "0",
                            "htd": "5",
                            "hi": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "16-01-2023": {
                "": {
                    "id_titular": null,
                    "titular": null,
                    "genero": null,
                    "asignaturas": [
                        {
                            "plan": "LICENCIATURA EN CONTADURÍA",
                            "name": "INGLÉS A - ",
                            "degree": "1",
                            "group": "B",
                            "hd": "0",
                            "ht": "0",
                            "htd": "4",
                            "hi": "0"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

La cuestión es que no he podido resolver el cómo indexar esos arrays, conozco la función **array_values** que hace precisamente lo que estoy buscando, pero no he sabido como aplicarlo, a continuación, muestro el código en php:

```
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($consulta, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
            $status = $row['ESTATUS'];  #NOS SIRVE PARA CREAR LAS DOS TIPOS DE CONTENIDO "N" o "MPA"
            $tipo_mov = $row['TIPO_MOV'];   #NOS SIRVE PARA VER SI ES UNA MATERIA NORMAL O EN CASO CONTRARIO ES UN MPA, MPB NO NOS SIRVE
            $periodo  = $row['FECHA_INICIO_MOV']; #PERIODO INICIO EN CASO DE NULL, ES PERIODO NORMAL, ALGUNA FECHA CASO CONTRARIO

            $titular = $row['ID_TITULAR']; #SIRVE PARA SABER SI ES UNA MATERIA INTERINA, NULL SI ES NORMAL, ALGUN NUMERO CASO CONTRARIO
            $apertura = $row['ID_APERTURA_CARGA']; #ID DE LA MATERIA

            // var_dump($tipo_mov);
            if (!array_key_exists($status, $fake_dictionary)) $fake_dictionary[$status] = []; ##aqui se separan los Estatus N y los MPA

            if (!array_key_exists($periodo, $fake_dictionary[$status])) $fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo] = []; ##aqui se separan los Estatus                

            if (!array_key_exists($titular, $fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo])) $fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo][$titular] = [
                "id_titular" => $row['ID_TITULAR'],
                "titular" => $row['NOMBRE_TITULAR'],
                "genero" => $row['GENERO'],
                "asignaturas" => []
            ]; ##aqui se separa si hay titutar


            if (!array_key_exists($apertura, $fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo][$titular]['asignaturas'])) {
                if ($tipo_mov == null || $tipo_mov == 'MPA') {

                    $cargas = [
                        "plan" => $row['CARR_DESCRIPCION'],
                        "name" => $row['ASIG_DESCRIPCION'],
                        "degree" => $row['PERIODO'],
                        "group"  => $row['GRUPO'],
                        "hd" => $row['CARGA_HD'],
                        "ht" => $row['CARGA_HT'],
                        "htd" => $row['CARGA_HTD'],
                        "hi" => $row['CARGA_HI']
                    ];
                    // array_push()
                    array_push($fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo][$titular]['asignaturas'], $cargas);
                }
            }
            
            $subjects[$titular] = [
                "id_titular" => $row['ID_TITULAR'],
                "titular" => $row['NOMBRE_TITULAR'],
                "genero" => $row['GENERO'],
                "asignaturas" => []
            ];

            array_push($subjects[$titular], $fake_dictionary[$status][$periodo][$titular]);

        }
        
        $respuesta['datos'] = $fake_dictionary;
```

intenté colocando

```
         array_values($fake_dictionary[$status]);
```

pero solo me indexó los estatus, y que en realidad son los únicos que me sirven como pueden ver, lo que intento hacer es indexar los dos siguientes niveles después del estatus, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, de antemano gracias

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por *indexar* en este contexto? Pon un breve ejemplo de cómo se muestran los datos actuales y del resultado que esperas obtener.

Comment: Lo que obtengo es algo parecido a esto:
`{ "N":{ "":{ "":{ "id_titular","asignaturas":[] },{ "id_titular","asignaturas":[] } } },
  "MPA":{} }`

En su lugar lo que busco es:
`[ "N":[ [ { "id_titular","asignaturas":[] },{ "id_titular","asignaturas":[] } ] ],
  "MPA":[] ]`

Comment: Me pregunto ¿qué es `$fake_dictionary` en ese contexto y además por qué no verificas contra los mismos datos en la base de datos, construyendo incluso un resultado tal y como lo deseas en la misma consulta SQL? Parecería que le quieres tirar a PHP un problema que debió ser resuelto a nivel de consulta SQL, con una consiguiente manipulación de datos a posteriori que puede llevar a datos erróneos o mal formados, como de hecho está ocurriendo.

Comment: Es parte de una función a la que asigno el comportamiento de las materias que tiene un profesor:
`$respuesta['datos'] = $fake_dictionary;` para luego retornar `$respuesta`, es la consulta sql la cual me trae los datos necesarios para determinar este comportamiento

Comment: Me refiero a incorporar ese dato a la consulta SQL y así filtrar los datos en la misma BD, trayendolos tal y como los necesitas evitando así filtrarlos posteriormente.

Comment: La consulta ya lo hace, esto es la construcción de una API